# Neo4j cypher return unknown error with modify node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm beginner about neo4j and I'm evaluating neo4j version 2.0.0 RC1 community edition.
I tried to delete a node from one million nodes using browser interface(i.e host:7474/browser/)
Even though match query without delete clause works fine, match query with delete return Unknown error.

The following query working fine and fast response

```
match (u:User{uid:'3282'}) return u
```

The delete query returning Unknown error

```
match (u:User{uid:'3282'}) delete u return u
```

The node labeled User contains one million nodes, so I guessed Unknown error is because of slow performance.
Also, setting property query return unknown error in like fashion.

Is it usual neo4j's write performance? Is there a way to resolve the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you're trying to return the node that you just deleted. You can delete without the return, which should work fine:

```
match (u:User{uid:'3282'}) delete u;
```

Comment: Thank you for responding me soon. Eventually both delete and delete with return query works fine. Neo4j might get something wrong when I tried to run the above queries. I tried to delete all one million nodes at an one query before I ran the both above queries, then neo4j returned also Unknown error. This question was right, but I remain a new question how to delete big data at once.
thanks